# Is there any way to execute 'ng-serve' when starting an app from ASP.Net Core?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

Currently, I have downloaded a theme and installed on the project. But whenever I click start button from the ASP.NET CORE, it launches C# project. When I execute `ng serve` then it launches the angular project. Is there any way to launch angular project by clicking `start button` from visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand so much your question,

If you look your startup.cs, in Configure function you has some like (see the line `spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start")`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   ....
   app.UseStaticFiles();
   app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
   app.UseMvc(routes =>{
        ...
   }
   app.UseSpa(spa =>
   {
      spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
      spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start"); //<--THIS LINE
   });
}
```

If you take a look to your package.json in ClientApp you see

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
     ...
  },
```

So, when it's launched the asp.NET Core, you really are executing `ng serve`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Look at the MSBuild Exec Target.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/exec-task?view=vs-2019

Comment: which task would I need to don't stuck my build?